# Changing textfield in Actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript, timer, textbox, countdown

And once again, Actionscript / Flash is driving me crazy.
I am trying to create a simple countdown timer. I have added a text to the stage (of the type "input text"). The name of the textfield is wtftext.

```
 var treffen = new Date(2012,8,24,00,00,00);

function countdown() 
{ 
 var jetzt = new Date();
// trace(jetzt);

 var rest = treffen - jetzt;
 rest = Math.floor(rest/1000); //umrechnung millisek. in sek      
// trace(rest);

 var std = Math.floor(rest/3600); 
// trace(std);
 var temp = rest - (std*3600);
 var min = Math.floor(temp/60); 
// trace(min);

 wtftext.text = std + " Hours " + min + " Min";
 trace(std + " Hours " + min + " Min");

} 
//initial:
//countdown();
//recurring:
setInterval(countdown,1000);
```

I know the calculations are right. But something goes wrong when the textfield contents are changed. After one second, all I get is

> r in

I think The "r in" must be related to the text that I typed into the textfield ("x remaining").
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it. Just had to remove the text that was initially added to the textfield.